# OnPaint crashes design mode when debug is starting

Tags: c#, onpaint, designmode

I'm making a simple control based on a button, but I can't change its background color inside the OnPaint event without generating an error in Visual Studio's design mode only.

I edited the OnPaint event to see the background color change in design mode, but I needed to check if this change is being made in design mode only, otherwise the Click event of the button wasnt working:

```
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            if (this.DesignMode)
            {
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            }
        }
```

I also needed to change the OnCreateControl event for the change to be applied at runtime:

```
        protected override void OnCreateControl()
        {
            base.OnCreateControl();

            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        }
```

This makes the button work perfectly as expected, but an error (System.InvalidOperationException) is thrown when starting the debug with the design page in focus. It looks like the OnPaint event tries to change the design while debug is active. The error only happens in the design, the form continues to work correctly.

[Design before debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqsAX.png)
[Design after debuggin whith the working form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Ih6.png)

This error is very annoying, because I need to reopen the design of the form I'm working on whenever I do a debug on it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Why would you want to change the background on each paint event? You set it once in the beginning.

Comment: You are not supposed to change control properties in `OnPaint`. Have you ever looked at the details of the *InvalidOperationException*. Maybe this is what it wants to tell you.

Comment: Because I'm going to make a custom button with difined BackColors, this is a simple exemple that shows the error, but the real code isn't that simple

Comment: Regardless of the real code, you are not supposed to do that. Either you *paint* in the OnPaint event, and then you choose the color each time, or you set *a property* once or don't mess with it in OnPaint.

Comment: I can change Font, FlatAppearance, Height properties for exemple, without any error, the backgroundo color is the only one that fires this exception

Comment: When you change a visual property like the background color, it invalidates the control, i.e. it triggers a paint event. You could easily end up in a sort of endless loop. The reason it does not happen in your case is an implementation detail. It might change in the next Windows version. Do not fight against fundamental concepts of Windows Forms. Instead, do it the way it was designed. Likely, the exception will no longer occur.